# Sublime Text 3 custom plugin not loading

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I tried the standard "Hello, World!" Sublime Text 3 custom plugin steps, using several sources:

- https://leanpub.com/writing-sublime-plugins/read#helloworld
- https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/plugins/
- http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/plugin-basics

But I kept running into a problem: the directory where ST was prompting me to save my new plugin .py file was:

```
/Users/[Username]/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/
```

So I made

```
/Users/[Username]/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/HelloWorld/
```

and

```
/Users/[Username]/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/HelloWorld/hello_world.py
```

...but this wouldn't load, and I couldn't run its commands.

However, when I put the file here:

```
/Users/[Username]/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/hello_world.py
```

...it loaded fine.

Answer (score 3):

Turned out I needed to store them instead like

```
/Users/[Username]/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/HelloWorld/hello_world.py
```

(without the "User" dir at the end.)

Though there have been requests online for loading of package files nested deeper, it appears that new custom plugin files don't load more than one level deeper than Packages/ ... though I'm a bit confused why I have many package files currently installed below Packages/User/[PackageName]/ .

Comment: I'm confused that it works this way, but can also confirm that moving my plugin from `User` up one level into `Packages` (or any other subdirectory of `Packages` *besides* `User` made it start working in Sublime.